# Expose module as global variable in Browserify

Tags: browserify

I have `third-party-module-b` that uses `third_party_module_a` global and have

```
require('third-party-module-a');
```

in entry point.

The problem is `third-party-module-a` follows UMD pattern and does not define `third_party_module_a` global if it detects modular environment.

I'm looking for Browserify transform to fix that.

The transform should essentially replace `require` (like Webpack [expose-loader](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#expose-loader)):

```
(typeof ... ? window : global).third_party_module_a = require('third-party-module-a');
```

Or append `require` to the top of every module (like Webpack [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#plugin-provideplugin)):

```
var third_party_module_a = require('third-party-module-a');
```

Is there such Browserify transform?

*Notice that [exposify](https://github.com/thlorenz/exposify) transform does exactly the opposite thing and doesn't seem to be helpful here, despite the name.*

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if you've seen this or not but they have a list of transforms available on their github.

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/wiki/list-of-transforms

Not sure on a specific one but thought this might help if you hadn't seen it

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it is not really an answer to the question. Sure, I've browsed this list twice before asking the question and have found nothing.